# Tracking xAPI (TINCAN) remote content

Tags: scorm2004, tin-can-api

I was going through the tincan api. We have multiple 3rd party vendors which might support tincan api based content.
Can tincan content being hosted on some LMS (other) be tracked on my own LMS?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. This mostly comes down to whether you control the content. If you control the content then a piece of content can send xAPI statements to *any* LRS that is publicly available to that content (IOW the content or LRS can't be behind a firewall preventing it, etc.). **But** the kicker is the credentials needed to access the LRS would either need to be known to the end user and provided by them (an unlikely scenario) or need to be stored with the content which makes it an inherently insecure LRS.

The better option, and the one that xAPI is specifically designed to help with is that the 3rd party LMS would forward the statements that it receives on to your LRS. Naturally this means establishing a relationship with those 3rd party LMSs and them having the capability to do so. Alternatively you can ask them to have a credential to allow you to poll the endpoint to get new data.

Finally you could use a bit of indirection, where the content in the 3rd party LMS is actually launched in your LMS and then communications go back to that 3rd party LMS. This means the 3rd party LMS doesn't have to support Tin Can packages. Rustici Software (shameless plug) provides a few solutions to make this work, check out more at https://scorm.com/scorm-solved/rustici-software-content-distribution-solutions/